# If a matrix is non diagonalizable, what other method can I use to calculate the nth power?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, exponentiation, diagonalization

First off, I have this matrix `A`:

```
1 0 3
1 0 2
0 5 0
```

I have calculated the eigenvalues, which are `(11-sqrt(141))/2` and `(11+sqrt(141))/2`. From what I understand, if I don't have 3 distinct eigenvalues then the matrix is not diagonalizable in R. Is this matrix diagonalizable in R?

The second part of my question is: if it's not diagonalizable then what other option do I have for calculating `A^n`? `n` is really big, something like the order of `10^12`. I need to calculate this for a programming problem.

Comment: I think you need a different approach to your problem. $A^n$ is going to have impossibly big entries for $n=10^{12}$. Already for $n=100$ we have the row 1, col 1 entry as 21569359182880372085408476588692190023999240141617216817121.

Comment: The eigenvalues are false, check on [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eigenvalues%5B%7B%7B1%2C+0%2C+3%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+0%2C+2%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+5%2C+0%7D%7D%5D)

Comment: you may be able to prove something by induction. Do a Jordan normal decomposition, as suggested, then see what you can do with it.

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues equals the sum of the diagonal entries. If your two eigenvalues are correct, then $-10$ must also be an eigenvalue.

Comment: The solution of the problem will be `mod 1000000006`. Thanks for pointing out that my calculations were wrong. :) First things first. I need to find out where I went wrong on calculating the eigenvalues and then proceed with the solution.

Comment: It is **not true** that if the three (in this case) eigenvalues aren't different then the matrix is *not* diagonalizable. For example, the unit matrix (of any order) has only one eigenvalue and it is diagonalizable.

Comment: Why on Earth should the solution be given mod 1000000006? Is this a problem from an ongoing competition? Project Euler, or codechef, or something like that?

Comment: Sort of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659045/efficient-solution-for-my-task-needed/25665342?noredirect=1#comment40167692_25665342 But anyway I wanted to find out how to do a diagonalization the right way.

Comment: Not really related to the math problem, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring is easier for computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Jordan decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) (diagonal matrix + nilpotent). But as pointed out in the comments, if you raise something to the power $10^{12}$, don't expect your computer to be able to handle it.

Comment: The solution of the problem will be `mod 1000000006`.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the eigenvalues:

$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-1&0&-3\\
-1&x&-2\\
0&-5&x\end{vmatrix}=x^2(x-1)-15-10(x-1)=x^3-x^2-10x-5$$

The above cubic has three rather ugly roots, all of them different...and thus the matrix is diagonalizable.